# Is there a way to disable noise cancellation on iOS using CoreAudio?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio

I'm during some audio processing with input from the phone's mic. I'd like to use the raw input from the mic.

I see that there is a setting to disable the noise cancellation in Settings->General->Accessibility, but I would prefer to do it programmatically rather than divert the user to Settings.

Does anyone have any experience with getting the raw mic input programatically, with CoreAudio or any other means?